# Elementor, funciones Javascript no funcionan en los popup

Tags: javascript, wordpress, popup, elementor, contact-form-7

Trabajo en elementor Pro y estoy trabajando en formularios de Contact form 7, les he agregado funcines para validar y para reformatear los campos (por ejemplo los puntos y guion en el número DNI, las mayusculas en el nombre y el punto y simbolo monetario al "monto").

Esto me ha funcionado bien en todos los formularios, excepto cuando el formulario esta dentro de un popup.

He llegado a pensar que este problema es debido a que el codigo del popup queda debajo del código js, pero no se como solucionar eso.

Si alguien conoce alguna solución, lo agradecería. Adjunto un ejemplo del formulario(el segundo botón es el que despliega el popup):
https://sitio-publico-coval-pruebas.azurewebsites.net/1-modulos-de-prueba/

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema es que contact form 7 interviene el submit, esto lo debe hacer cuando se carga la página. Lo interviene para convertirlo en asíncrono. El contenido de tu ventana modal no existe cuando se carga la página, por lo que contact form 7 no hace esa intervención, por lo que el submit se ejecuta de manera síncrona, es decir, como cualquier request. Prueba si existe una manera que el modal se cargue en el inicio de la página

Answer (score 0):

El código de los pop-ups de elementor se añaden siempre en última posición, por lo tanto no puedes poner un "Custom Code" de JS por debajo suya.

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir un widget html dentro del pop-up y debajo del Form. Ahí dentro del Script añádes tu código Javascript
[image: Widget HTML- Elementor]

Comment: o quizas añadirle la propiedad "defer" al script lo que aseguraria que se ejecute despues de cargarse el DOM